# How to Store Different Data from Text File into ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I've been asked to create a staff phone book in the form of an array that will hold their names followed by their extension number. The phone book is to support several functions:

1. Adding new entries that will be inserted in alphabetical order of surname
2. Delete entries by name or number
3. Lookup name given name
4. Change number
5. Print entire telephone directory

So nothing advanced, however the issue I am having lies with the text file and getting the information stored correctly in the array(s). The text file contains the data separated by tabs in the following format:

Surname<--TAB-->Initials<--TAB-->Extension

I believe from how the assignment is worded, I am being asked to first load the populated text file data into arrays in the program which will then be manipulated using the functions I mentioned before. They explicitly stated that writing back to the file is not necessary here.

So far I have created several classes that contains the general information for each object that will be used in the project (I.e. Entry class, Directory interface [required], ArrayDirectory class, DirectoryFile class). I am trying to read the 3 different items in from the text file and then store it in an Entry object which I created a constructor for. I know how I will use the methods, I just can't create this initial link between the text file and my array which is meaning I can't progress at all yet. I have tried implementing solutions found online but that proved to be more confusing.

Since I am saving the data as a custom object (Entry) I have also ran into problems here and have ended up being really confused.

#### Entry Class

```
public class Entry {

    private String firstName = null;
    private String surname = null;
    private String extension = null;

    public Entry(String firstName, String surname, String extension) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.extension = extension;
    }

...(getters and setters, toString)...
```

#### ArrayDirectory Class

```
public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

    private final static int MAX_ENTRIES = 20;
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    DirectoryFile file = new DirectoryFile("C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\Phonebook.txt");
    static List<Entry> phonebook = new ArrayList<>(MAX_ENTRIES);

    public void addEntry() throws IOException {
        // check if phone book is empty before loading entries
        System.out.println(phonebook.isEmpty());
        loadEntries(file.getFile());
        System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
        String fname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter second name: ");
        String sname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter telephone extension: ");
        String telephone = input.nextLine();

        Entry entry = new Entry(fname, sname, telephone);
        phonebook.add(entry);
        System.out.println("Added staff member: \n" + fname + "\n" + sname + "\n" + telephone);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phonebook.toArray()));

    }

    public String loadEntries(File file) throws IOException {
        String surname = null, fname = null, extension = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                String arr[] = line.split("\\s+");
                surname = arr[0];
                fname = arr[1];
                extension = arr[2];
                Entry entry = new Entry(surname, fname, extension);
                phonebook.add(entry);
                line = br.readLine();

            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

...(other methods for functionality, testing etc.)...
```

#### DirectoryFile Class

```
public class DirectoryFile {

    private File file;

    public DirectoryFile(String fileName) {
        this.file = new File(fileName);
    }

    public DirectoryFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that when running the loadEntries() method, it gives an OutOfBoundsException and states **index 1 out of bounds for length 1**. I think I may have the return signature for the method incorrect too however this is confusing me more. Should I pass the phone book ArrayList into the method instead of having a String return?

Sorry this is my first post ever asking for help online so apologies if I have repeated myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much time now but here's what I've done for u......
modify your `Entry` class to implement `Comparable` and override equals() like this:

```
public class Entry implements Comparable {

        private String firstName = null;
        private String surname = null;
        private String extension = null;

        public Entry(String firstName, String surname, String extension) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.extension = extension;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object arg0) {//important for sorting
            this.surname.compareTo(((Entry) arg0).surname);
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object arg0) {//important for deleting
            return ((Entry) arg0).firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.firstName);
        }
    }
```

Here are the other aditional methods:

```
    public void writetofile(List<Entry> entry) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("path");
        try (Writer w = new FileWriter(f); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(w);) {
            for (Entry e : entry) {
                String line = e.surname + "--------" + e.firstName + "--------" + e.extension;
                pw.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public List<Entry> sortbysurname(List<Entry> entry) {
        Collections.sort(entry);
        return entry;
    }

    // returns the index of the entry
    public boolean deleteByName(String name, List<Entry> entry) {
        return entry.remove(new Entry(name, "", ""));
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't test it by I hope it'll work fine. If there's any challenge let drop a comment and ill take a look after the Sabbath

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only just checked the site as didn't receive email notification. Could you check my edited post and see if you could help me out with the loadEntries() method? I need it to load all the data from the text file and store each line as an Entry object and store in the phone book ArrayList. When I run the loadEntries() method it gives me an OutOfBounds exception error because apparently index 1 is out of bounds for length 1...?

Comment: definitely because `fname = arr[1];` is trying to access an index that is not available. Your criteria in `line.split("\\s+");` is only returning an array of size 1